# Ajax table row to require authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have another question since everyone was so nice last time.
How can I make a certain row in a table in ajax to be shown only if you are logged in? I ask this here because I didn't find the answer anywhere and I have no idea how to do that on myself. So if you guys can explain that would be thankful.

Here is the ajax table

```
    /* Add new Post table row */
function manageRow(data) {
    var rows = '';
    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
        rows = rows + '<tr>';
        rows = rows + '<td>'+value.title+'</td>';
        rows = rows + '<td>'+value.icon+'</td>';
        rows = rows + '<td>'+value.user+'</td>';
        rows = rows + '<td>'+value.details+'</td>';
        rows = rows + '<td>'+value.created_at+'</td>';
        rows = rows + '<td data-id="'+value.id+'">';
        rows = rows + '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="btn btn-warning edit-item">Edit</button> ';
        rows = rows + '<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">Delete</button>';
        rows = rows + '</td>';
        rows = rows + '</tr>';
    });
    $("tbody").html(rows);
}
```

And I want those 2 rows to not be seen if you are not logged in.

```
rows = rows + '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="btn btn-warning edit-item">Edit</button> ';
rows = rows + '<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">Delete</button>';
```

I hope you guys can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do we know if your user is logged in?

Comment: expand your function by parameter "signedIn" and check if it is true. ofc you have to pass that parameter, too!

Comment: using ternary operator, you could write 
        `rows += (signedIn ? '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="btn btn-warning edit-item">Edit</button> ' : '');
        rows += (signedIn ? '<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">Delete</button>' : '');`

Comment: @Manticore Please post your answers as answers (instead of comments)…

Comment: @feeela actually i did not really believe this was the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd go for something like this:

```
/* Add new Post table row */
function manageRow(data, isLoggedIn)
{
    var rows = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value)
    {
        rows += '<tr>';
        rows += '<td>' + value.title + '</td>';
        rows += '<td>' + value.icon + '</td>';
        rows += '<td>' + value.user + '</td>';
        rows += '<td>' + value.details + '</td>';
        rows += '<td>' + value.created_at + '</td>';
        rows += '<td data-id="' + value.id + '">';

        if (isLoggedIn)
        {
            rows += '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="btn btn-warning edit-item">Edit</button> ';
            rows += '<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">Delete</button>';
        }

        rows += '</td>';
        rows += '</tr>';
    });

    $("tbody").html(rows);
}
```

However, this depends on your security concerns, it would be trivial for a hacker to mess with this and gain access to the two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a variable to determine if you have logged in. 'isLogin'.

```html
if(isLogin){// Need your background pass value
  rows = rows + '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="btn btn-warning edit-item">Edit</button> ';
  rows = rows + '<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">Delete</button>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Please use a local variable 
var IsUserLoggedin = false;
//Set it to true when your logged in 

function manageRow(data) {
    var rows = '';
    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
        rows = rows + '<tr>';
        rows = rows + '<td>'+value.title+'</td>';
        rows = rows + '<td>'+value.icon+'</td>';
        rows = rows + '<td>'+value.user+'</td>';
        rows = rows + '<td>'+value.details+'</td>';
        rows = rows + '<td>'+value.created_at+'</td>';
  rows = rows + '<td data-id="'+value.id+'">';
  if(IsUserLoggedin)
  {
   rows = rows + '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="btn btn-warning edit-item">Edit</button> ';
   rows = rows + '<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">Delete</button>';
  }   
  rows = rows + '</td>';
        rows = rows + '</tr>';
    });
    $("tbody").html(rows);
}
```